# Docker is not creating new container but recreates running one

Tags: caching, docker, docker-compose

so I have the following problem. I'm using docker-compose to build and start two container. I did this multiple times with different docker-compose.yml files (image and container name differ) and it worked fine and three container run parallel. The only difference is, that one container exposes a specific port and the other runs an application that connects to a specific endpoint.
So in total the containers are not that different, but they are.

But now I created three additional compose configurations and tried to run them parallel like I'm already doing with the three others. The Problem now is, that with docker-compose, one container is being build and started. But the second one will stop the created container and recreate it.
I tried to do `docker-compose build --no-cache` and after that `docker-compose up -d`, but I still ended up with the same problem. The images though were different (ID). Before that I tried it just with `docker-compose up -d --build` for the first and second (new) container and it would be recreated like mentioned. But looking at the images, they would get the same ID (but different name).

So I thought docker has a problem with caching. That's why I ended up deleting all my container and images and started from scratch with the option `--no-cache` like mentioned above. Didn't work though.

Here are two docker-compose.yml that work:

```
version: '2'
services:
    ruby:
        security_opt:
            - seccomp:unconfined
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_ruby
            args:
                - http_proxy=http://someIP:3128
                - https_proxy=http://someIP:3128
        image: ruby_foo_ge01
        container_name: ruby_container_ge01
        volumes:
            - /home/foo/log/GE01/:/usr/src/app/log/
    ssl:
        security_opt:
            - seccomp:unconfined
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_ssl
            args:
                - http_proxy=http://someIP:3128
                - https_proxy=http://someIP:3128
        image: ssl_ge01
        container_name: ssl_container_ge01
        volumes:
            - /home/foo/log/GE01/nginx/:/var/log/nginx/
        ports:
            - "3003:443"
        links:
            - ruby
```

and the other one:

```
version: '2'
services:
    ruby:
        security_opt:
            - seccomp:unconfined
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_ruby
            args:
                - http_proxy=http://someIP:3128
                - https_proxy=http://someIP:3128
        image: ruby_foo
        container_name: ruby_container
        volumes:
            - /home/foo/log/:/usr/src/app/log/
    ssl:
        security_opt:
            - seccomp:unconfined
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_ssl
            args:
                - http_proxy=http://someIP:3128
                - https_proxy=http://someIP:3128
        image: ssl_gt01
        container_name: ssl_container
        volumes:
            - /home/foo/log/nginx/:/var/log/nginx/
        ports:
            - "3001:443"
        links:
            - ruby
```

Running this two and one other quite similar with `docker-compose up -d --build` is no problem.

And here are two .yml files of the container that fail:

```
version: '2'
services:
    ruby:
        security_opt:
            - seccomp:unconfined
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_ruby
            args:
                - http_proxy=http://someIP:3128
                - https_proxy=http://someIP:3128
        image: ruby_foo_websock_gt01
        container_name: ruby_containerWSgt01
        volumes:
            - /home/foo/websockGT01/log/:/usr/src/app/log/
    ssl:
        security_opt:
            - seccomp:unconfined
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_ssl
            args:
                - http_proxy=http://someIP:3128
                - https_proxy=http://someIP:3128
        image: ssl_websock_gt01
        container_name: ssl_containerWSgt01
        volumes:
            - /home/foo/websockGT01/log/nginx/:/var/log/nginx/
        ports:
            - "3010:443"
        links:
            - ruby
```

And the second one:

```
version: '2'
services:
    ruby:
        security_opt:
            - seccomp:unconfined
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_ruby
            args:
                - http_proxy=http://someIP:3128
                - https_proxy=http://someIP:3128
        image: ruby_foo_websock_ge01
        container_name: ruby_containerWSge01
        volumes:
            - /home/foo/websockGE01/log/:/usr/src/app/log/
    ssl:
        security_opt:
            - seccomp:unconfined
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_ssl
            args:
                - http_proxy=http://someIP:3128
                - https_proxy=http://someIP:3128
        image: ssl_websock_ge01
        container_name: ssl_containerWSge01
        volumes:
            - /home/foo/websockGE01/log/nginx/:/var/log/nginx/
        ports:
            - "3030:443"
        links:
            - ruby
```

As you can see there is no big difference in the working .yml files and the ones that fail. (Or did I miss something?) The image and container names change as does the exposed port and volume path.
All of the files have their own working dir where also the application code is saved per instance. All the used Dockerfiles are the same in each working dir.

**TL;DR**: Why is my docker-compose not starting a new container, but stops a running one and recreates that one? Is there a maximum amount of running container? Have I done something wrong in my .yml file? As mentioned at the beginning `--no-cache` does not help.

Kind regards and sorry for that wall of text

Comment: I don't see how this can help me. I don't want to end a container, but create a new one and let it run with the others. But docker-compose just ends and recreates it. Maybe I just don't understand what you want to tell me here. But to answer your question: no, I didn't.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Short(ish) answer**

It looks as though you're using the same project name some of the time when you run `docker-compose up`; since you use the same service names (i.e. `ruby` and `ssl`) between `docker-compose.yml` files, Docker Compose treats the different configurations as modifications of the same service, rather than considering them to be separate services completely.

My guess is that the parent directory of some of the `docker-compose.yml` files is the same, so if you want to run these containers at the same time you have a few options:

- Change the names of the parent directories so they're all different
- Specify a different project name on each invocation of `docker-compose up`, e.g. `docker-compose -p project1 up -d`, `docker-compose -p project2 up -d`
- Change the service names so they're not all the same across the different `docker-compose.yml` files

**Longer answer**

From a quick test it appears that Docker Compose uses the project name and service name to identify a specific service.  The project name can be set with the `-p` flag when running Docker Compose commands, otherwise it uses the value of the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable if set, and if neither of those are specified it'll default to the name of the parent directory of the `docker-compose.yml` file (see https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview).

So, given a directory structure such as:

```
.
├── a
│   └── z
│       └── docker-compose.yml
├── b
│   └── z
│       └── docker-compose.yml
└── c
    └── y
        └── docker-compose.yml
```

Running `docker-compose up -d` from the `a/z` directory (or using `docker-compose -f a/z/docker-compose.yml up -d`) will start `ruby` and `ssl` services in project `z`, named using the container names specified in the `docker-compose.yml`.

If you then run `docker-compose up -d` from the`b/z` directory, Docker Compose will see you trying to again bring up the `ruby` and `ssl` services in project `z`, but this time with some differences, e.g. to names and ports.  It will treat this as if you had modified the original `docker-compose.yml`, and restart the containers with the new configuration.  If you were to now run `docker-compose up -d` from the `c/y` directory then you would get two new containers running in parallel with the first two, `ruby` and `ssl` services running in project `y`.

So you'll need to ensure that the combination of project and service name differs across the different sets of containers you'd like to run, either by changing the service names or by setting the project differently each time.

Comment: I have in fact the three of those not working .yml files in a folder that has the same name (but the parent of that one is different). I will try this out, but this sounds very promissing.

Comment: Just tested this and that realy was the problem. Thank you very much.