# Docker compose is using existing mysql container instead of new container when two services have same mysql config

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

I have two projects. Both uses docker-compose for deployment.
Both of them have a mysql container.

For the first one I have the following configuration for mysql inside docker-compose file.

```
  mysql: 
    image: mysql:latest
    env_file: mysql.env 
    ports: 
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - my-network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "mysqladmin ping -h localhost -P 3306"]
      interval: 1s
      retries: 10
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
```

The first docker-compose file is run and is working fine.

My mysql env file is given below.

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root123@23
MYSQL_DATABASE=db1
MYSQL_USER=db_user_1
MYSQL_PASSWORD=db_pass1
MYSQL_PORT_INTERNAL=3306
MYSQL_HOST=mysql
MYSQL_PORT_EXTERNAL=3306
```

I have the second docker-compose file with the following entry for mysql

```
  mysql: 
    image: mysql:latest
    env_file: mysql.env 
    ports: 
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - my-new-network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "mysqladmin ping -h localhost -P 3306"]
      interval: 1s
      retries: 10
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
```

Only difference is that, in the mysql.env file i have set different credentials.
The second env file is given below.

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root124@24
MYSQL_DATABASE=db2
MYSQL_USER=db_user_2
MYSQL_PASSWORD=db_pass2
MYSQL_PORT_INTERNAL=3306
MYSQL_HOST=mysql
MYSQL_PORT_EXTERNAL=3306
```

When I run the second docker-compose file application is failing to connect to the MYSQL.
So I changed the second env file and modified its contents with that from first env file.
When I ran that, it is connecting to the mysql.

To make sure that it is using the second docker-compose mysql configuraton, I made the all services in first docker compose file down.
Ran again. Still it works only with the credentials as in first env file.
What I understood is that, it might be using the same image as the first one. So when then second docker-compose file is ran, it builds the first image.

To troubleshoot further,  I made the mysql volumn names different in the two docker compose files, just to make sure that it is not an issue related with volumn.

But still it works only with credentials from the first env file.

I need to know why this is happening and the solution for this.

Comment: I'm quite sure your only problem is that you are mapping the same local port to your docker host and that the MySQL service in the second project does not start. Just drop the port configuration and try again.

Comment: When you ty again, you should also make sure you're not starting either db instance on a pre-existing volume so that MySQL is fully configured on start using your env Vars. See [this question](/q/59838692) for more details.

Comment: In the two projects, are the Compose files in directories with the same name (for example, `project1/docker/docker-compose.yml` and `project2/docker/docker-compose.yml`)?  Compose uses that last directory name as a _project name_ and this behavior is also consistent with Compose thinking they're the same project.  [Docker is not creating new container but recreates running one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126022/docker-is-not-creating-new-container-but-recreates-running-one) describes a similar problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze In both projects, directory name is same - infrastructure

Comment: @Zeitounator I am not running both projects simultaneously. Containers of only one project is active at a time.

Comment: You are exactly in the situation [I already linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59838692). Since you used the same name for your project, when you start the firts one, your mysql container will init the db with the env vars found there. When you stop it and move to the second project, since it has the same name, the container will reuse the exact same volume which already contains an initialized db so it will simply ingnore your envvars. You need to have different names for your projects. You can either rename the dirs, pass a name on the command line or set the name in .env file.